# Can't connect to neo4j database on port 80

Tags: neo4j, neo4django

I managed to get **neo4j** up and running on port *80* on another machine.. I am trying to use **django** and **neo4django** to connect to the database.

I am getting the error : No such database exists: %s

This happens when I try to do a .objects.get() on any of my neo4django models. The reason for this is in C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\neo4django\db\models\base.py in _neo4j_instance 
where

```
names = [name for name in connections
        if connections[name].url in neo_node.url]
```

As I am using port 80, neo_node.url removes the ':80' in the url, but connections[name].url does not, causing the condition above to fail and returning an empty list. I am trying to figure out a workaround for this, but to no avail. As I am planning to use heroku to host my app, I cannot modify the neo4django files.

Comment: Could you share the relevant versions (Django, Neo4j and neo4django) and the NEO4J_DATABASES setting in settings.py?

Comment: If you think the behavior is an error, I'd raise an issue on GitHub (https://github.com/scholrly/neo4django/issues) - I'll look into it for the next release.

Comment: I am using Django 1.4.5, Neo4j 1.9, neo4django 0.1.8 .

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in the library. If you could raise an issue, I'd be happy to try to find a fix for the next release.

Since you're using Neo4j 1.9, I'd also suggest you upgrade to the latest neo4django off GitHub- 0.1.8 only supports up to 1.8.2.